# FCC certification for multiple transmitters

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, fcc, certification

Need help in understanding FCC certification for a IoT device with a Bluetooth module and a WiFi module.

The Bluetooth has its own FCC ID, so does WiFi. Both are certified to be modular FCC certified. So I presume that my product needs to have a single FCC ID, whose tests would involve simultaneous transmission.

Is there a way to do only few additional tests (simultaneous transmission), without going for product level FCC, and still sell the product?
Also, does anyone have an idea on how do phone manufacturers handle this, because they have BT, WiFi, LTE as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Your product needs its own certification to confirm that its unintentional and intentional radiation is within allowable limits. A RF testing lab should be able to help you identify the tests your product needs.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass FCC 47, section 15 to show that you conform to the EMC standard for the USA. The tests are required for your product, as it is an intentional emitter, as well in an unintentional emitter.

If you are looking at other markets, you'll see you have other standards which you'll have to meet. Pick up your mouse, keyboard, monitor, computer, and you'll see a plethora of other logos along with FCC: CE, CASA, CAS and others. There is a different set for different countries, or groups of countries, most are defined in this document here: https://www.ieee.li/pdf/essay/guide_to_global_emc_requirements_2007.pdf

In answer to the "how do other companies deal with this" is they do lots of testing and follow any read-across that they can find. Most test houses will be happy to help with this.

Don't forget, if the IoT device is to go in a car, it will need to conform to the automotive standards (which has even more variation than home equipment) and there are also medical and military standards which may have an influence depending on your device and where it ends up.

My advice is to contact a local test house and ask them what they recommend for your target market.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am in touch with UL for this, but my question is - As a host who is integrating two independant FCC approved modules, I understand I have to perform the tests as per FCC requirements with simultaneous use case (both BT and WiFi transmitting same time). No regulation says I need to get a FCC ID for my product. Am I right ?

Comment: But your product does presumably not JUST contain those two modules... There is probably some other digital electronics in there, and I would guess it is operating at more then 9kHz?